# PHP Dynamic Form Fields

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4

I'm doing a project using Laravel 4.2. In my project I have a form which is used to create a new Course. It has a dynamic part which is used to add Subjects to the Course. When someone presses the Add button it will pop up another form to fill in the Subject details. When Save is pressed the values will be stored in a session array until post.

My question is:

> Is it good to keep subjects values in the session, or is any their
>   better way handle dynamic form fields?

Comment: Have you consider doing this storing the information on local storage?, I would say it's a good usage of it, then validate everything on the server (while also doing it via JS on the F/E), IMHO, it would be the best as it's stored on the user's browser, and won't go away if for example your server restarts while the user was filling the form, and by you having the data on the session you would cause that data to get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Session Array should be used to carry user information from one page to another but saving form data in session is not an good  option. What you can do is use `$_POST[]` array to save the form data and receive on other side using `$_POST['value']`. It would have been better if you would have provided some of the code.